# Is it really necessary to write Java code to display the Up Navigation Button in Android?

Tags: java, android

When I want to provide Up Navigation in the ActionBar of an Android activity, I just write these lines of code in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

However, now I've just saw these lines of code in the java file:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

All my previous projects just worked without the these lines of Java. Are they really necessary? If they are, are they necessary for compatibility for android versions? In this case, previous to which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using *Appcompat* which is a  compatibility library to access and customize different ui elements known as views on api 7<= .
When you override "*onOptionsItemSelected*", you add a custom action to a button on the action bar (so now isnthe implementation of *NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)*).
So let your activity extend AppCompatActivity (if it isn't already).

Comment: don't you still need to call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` with AppCompatActivity to show the arrow?

Comment: So, if I'm not working with API 7 or less and I don't need a different behavior than the default one, I don't need to write any java code, right?

Comment: Yes both of you, unless you need some specific features not present in older sdk level (Android studio should warn you in case).